# LibGDX Particles not the same as in Editor

Tags: libgdx, particle-system, particles

I've created a "snow" particle effect using LibGDX's ParticleEditor, and exported the effect to a `snow.p` file.

When I load the file in my game it looks completely different.

As seen in the editor:
[image: Snow Effect as shown in ParticleEditor]

As seen in game:
[image]

As you can see the editor shows the snow falling throughout the space. Can't tell from the image, but it's falling downwards.

In the game, the snow "falls" along a line and to the right. I opened the `p` file in a text editor, and it looks fine so I'm not sure what is wrong.

In case it's needed, here is how I load and use the particle effect.

```
ParticleEffect p = new ParticleEffect();
p.load(Gdx.files.internal("snow.p"), Gdx.files.internal(""));
p.setPosition(0, DonutsGame.WORLD_HEIGHT / 2);
addActor(new ParticleEffectActor(p));
```

The actor class:

```
public class ParticleEffectActor extends Actor {
   ParticleEffect effect;

   public ParticleEffectActor(ParticleEffect effect) {
      this.effect = effect;
      effect.start();
   }

   public void draw(SpriteBatch batch, float parentAlpha) {
      effect.draw(batch); //define behavior when stage calls Actor.draw()
   }

   public void act(float delta) {
      super.act(delta);
      effect.update(delta); //update it
   }
}
```

I can post the `snow.p` file, but it's a bit large, if there's a particular section that would be helpful let me know and I will post it.

Comment: Looks like a 2D effect being looked at with a PerspectiveCamera that's sitting on the X-Y plane looking parallel to the plane.

Comment: It was a stupid mistake, though not completely my fault. The editor wasn't showing the effect correctly. I gave up - quit the editor, and came back to it an hour later. When I loaded my `snow.p` file in the editor the result was the same as in the game.